# Compressing efficiency

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, gzip

There is a task to save data in some local storage or for network transmission. Data are stored in plain object form (key-value pairs).
With the aim to save bandwith and storage space I'm planning to use the conversion from long verbose key names to corresponding digits (using map) and restore them on receiving data. For example:

```
var statesMap = {
    SEARCH: 0,
    SORT: 1,
    FILTER: 2,
    DISPLAY_FAV: 3,
    PANEL_POS: 4,
    MENU_LIST_POS: 5,
    MAIN_LIST_POS: 6,
    INFO_LIST_POS: 7,
    CHANNEL: 8
};

config = {
        APP: ['SEARCH', 'SORT', 'DISPLAY_FAV', 'PANEL_POS', 'MENU_LIST_POS', 'MAIN_LIST_POS', 'CHANNEL']
    };

app.state = {};

// restore state from {"0":"ui","1":"NAME","3":false,"4":0,"5":3,"6":0}
config[appName.toUpperCase()].forEach(function ( state ) {
    var value = storage[statesMap[state]]; // 'storage' stores my data
    // convert "compressed" properties to full equivalents
    app.state[state] = value != null ? value : '';
});

// result {"SEARCH":"ui","SORT":"NAME","DISPLAY_FAV":false,"PANEL_POS":0,"MENU_LIST_POS":3,"MAIN_LIST_POS":0,"CHANNEL":""}

// store data
var tmp = {};

// filter fields with empty values, don't store them
Object.keys(app.state).filter(function ( key ) { return !!String(app.state[key]); }).forEach(function ( state ) {
    tmp[statesMap[state]] = app.state[state];
});

storage = tmp;
```

Are there sufficient benefits and advantages with this approach? Are there better optimizations? Does this optimization interfere with gzip compression algorithm?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Every single bit ypu change will interfeer with gzip compression. If you do this, disable gzip. You will force the server and browser to try to optimize something that is impossible to compress. Gzip and any other compression algorithm is only effective when used with a certain minimum ammount of data. But if you do this, be prepared to pull your hairs out when you have to debug it in the future.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - that's simply false. There are certain types of transformations that interfere with gzip working, and there are others that don't (indeed, pre-processing data is a very common technique to improve compression prior to handing off to a general-purpose algorithm). The type of transformation described here probably won't hurt or help much, but if I had to guess, it could have a small benefit. It removes some redundancy, but doesn't obscure in any way the remaining redundancy, so gzip will be fine with it.

Comment: @BeeOnRope I have 2 things to say. First is "What...?". The second is: If you change 1 bit, you can be sure that gzip may behave differently. Lets say with this: `[1,0,1]` and `[1,1,1]`. On the first example, it wouldn't be able to compress anything, but it **could** on the 2nd, since `1,` is repeated. Also, if you try to compress `[1,1,1]`, it will return a string with **25 bytes** (+18 bytes than the initial data). That is without the headers. You can see it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a3b05f8f6ec994dd9cc20b6254e74b76cf6c9224

Comment: Of course if you change 1 bit gzip will behave differently. There are plenty of transformations that will screw gzip over (e.g., anything that breaks the byte-alignment of data, like encoding into base-64, or anything that breaks up matches). We are talking about the _specific_ example the OP mentioned about replacing long key names with integers. gzip won't have a problem with that at all. You'll probably get slightly better overall size by doing it (but a lower compression ratio - because you are removing some of the redundancy yourself).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - regarding the **25 bytes** - your point is lost on me. Of course compression algorithms generally have some overhead, which results in an expansion on short strings, but still encoding a _shorter string_ generally results in a _shorter output_. There is not some magic threshold where the size shoots up. Try it - take a 10,000 character string, and then graph the compressed size vs input size for that string and all the 10,000 prefixes of that string (i.e., chopping off a byte at a time).

Comment: @BeeOnRope Man, you aren't making any sense! Look, here's a new example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d8d0799147e3256ede2b730cb1ded7cf66c1eb67 (this uses the content available as example on the first comment, which I will quote: `// restore state from {"0":"ui","1":"NAME","3":false,"4":0,"5":3,"6":0}`). The gzipped output is 64 bytes, while the content is 49 bytes. This is using the output given as example. I believe that, **FOR THE TEST CASE THAT THE O.P. IS SHOWING, AND IT'S FINAL RESULT**, it isn't worth it since it will nullify the results of gzipping the output.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - yes, of course, for very small strings gzip isn't going to help - I don't htink that was up for debate? The question was whether doing his string key -> integer mapping was going to "break gzip". So gzip the full version without numbers, the final output is [larger than the transformed version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/506f576b8821595278481fa9bf9e0ed7795ddf12).

Comment: The claim I'm arguing against is "every single bit you change will interfere with gzip compression" and "impossible to compress". The transformation the OP suggestion doesn't interfere with gzip per-se. Of course, if the strings are _very_ short, gzip may not be useful: it's not useful for the exact example above for either the original or transformed string, so that's neither here nor there. gzip is only viable for longer strings, so let's assume the typical strings are long?

Comment: It was up for debate. That is the whole point. The generated JSON will be smaller (and would be EVEN SMALLER if it was proper JSON, since the data is an array shoehorned as an object) and, in the worst case, repetition-free. How will gzip compress something that is smaller than the size it is effective at, without repeated data? You will see that the output will be **impossible to compress**. And yes, I stand by the fact that changing a single bit may interfeer with gzip. I didn't say anything about breaking gzip. I said the output may be totally different if you change a single bit.

Comment: The question wasn't whether gzip should be used - that was specified as a **given** in the question - it was whether this replacement will be fruitful given that it will pass through gzip later. Let's give the OP the benefit of the doubt and assume that the gzip encoding comes as part of the http accept-encoding for the entire request, which is presumably larger than the snippet of json shown above. I assume he's not just taking this short string and trying to gzip it alone as in your sandbox example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimization you are referring to might be called "token replacement" or something like that and is a reasonable approach to domain-specific compression.

This type of transformation doesn't prevent matching+entropy based algorithms like gzip from working, and so you aren't likely to get a *larger final size* after applying this transformation. That said, the replacement you are doing is *exactly* the type of thing that gzip is good at doing, so doing it yourself before invoking gzip may be a bit redundant.

To know for sure, you can simply test! What are the typical results of your token replacement + gzip, versus gzip alone?

Even without testing, here are some advantages and disadvantages of the token replacement-before-gzip based approach:

#### Advantages

1. Sometimes you can do the token replacement more efficiently than gzip, if you do it early in the output generation, and can use this more compact form through most of your processing chain. You may get speedups in other parts of your code because things like string comparisons are now replaced by very fast integer comparisons (however, see disadvantage #1).
2. gzip has certain limitations based partly on its age and huge range of target hardware, that you can work around with your token replacement. For example, it only finds matches in a 32 KiB window, while your token replacement works on the entire format.
3. Token replacement effectively takes advantage of your knowledge of the format to encode more efficiently than gzip could. For example, although gzip will perform largely the same substitutions as you are for frequently occurring keys, your replacement will do well for infrequently occurring keys (but this doesn't matter if there are a lot of them). In effect, you are able to make use of a pre-distributed out of band dictionary, which helps compression.

#### Disadvantages

1. Gzip is usually efficiently implemented using native libraries provided by your OS or runtime environment. Especially since you are calling gzip anyways, *just* using gzip is may be faster than doing your token replacement at the language level. How much faster (or slower) depends a lot on your implementation.
2. Compression-wise gzip is largely doing the same replacement operation you are (plus many more), so replacing tokens yourself is somewhat redundant. That is, gzip looks for "matches": strings that already occurred earlier in the text, and replaces them with tokens, just like you do. Plus it does a lot of other good stuff, like entropy coding the tokens, so you want it as a final step no matter what.
3. Adding your own pre-compression step may not *harm* compression (even if it doesn't help it much), but it adds complexity, a source for bugs, possibly performance issues and so on. You need to somehow transmit the key <-> integer mapping to remote clients, etc, etc.

Basically, I would recommend *against it*, unless your testing shows that it provides a significant performance boost. Usually it won't, since gzip is already removing most of the redundancy, but it depends on the specifics of your situation.

Comment: If performance is an issue, or if you see yourself encoding the same string tons of times, you could implement a decent caching system, where the output is stored compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on your question.

If you use your idea, don't use gzip or use it when the data is longer than *x* bytes.

The best is to do not use it.

---

This is why I say to do not use your method:

- Readability is more important than saving 30 bytes
- You add complexity on the server and client code
- It difficults debugging, since nothing is clear anymore
- Expandability is extremelly difficult and prone to errors.

Using your method has the following advantages:

- If you are accessing the data from a browser without gzip support, this will still save you bandwidth
- Since you know the format, you can achieve better compression without gzip

But, you have to consider this:

- Gzip (and all compression formats) work better with bigger and repeated data. That is where they shine. If you remove the redundancy yourself and send a small output, you're wasting processing power to only increase the output size. This output without redudancy is impossible to compress.
- Using your method will reduce the readability significativelly and remove all the flexibility. It will force you to place all required data at the beginning and the optional at the end. It won't fit every test case you might have and will force you to increase your logic code to deal with that.

One example is, if in the future, you want to add debugging information or fields that you wont always return. Here's a very basic example:

- If the operation succeeds: `{"error":false,[... data goes here ...]}`
- If some "soft-error" happens (eg: failed validation): `{"error":true,"type":"..."}`
- If a nasty error happened: `{"error":500,"desc":"Service unavaliable"}`

With your code, the 2nd field can either be `"desc"`, `"type"` or anything.

You could say: "We can add the `desc` and `type` fields and always send them!". And now, you are adding **more** data, defeating the reason to use your method.

---

**Backing up my claims**

What kind of answer would mine be without some data do backup bold statements like "impossible to compress"?

Lets consider your example data:

```
{"SEARCH":"ui","SORT":"NAME","DISPLAY_FAV":false,"PANEL_POS":0,"MENU_LIST_POS":3,"MAIN_LIST_POS":0,"CHANNEL":""}
```

Which you (non-optimally) reduced to this:

```
{"0":"ui","1":"NAME","3":false,"4":0,"5":3,"6":0}
```

All the compression values will be using this base PHP code:

```
$output = '<content>';

echo 'gzip:', strlen(gzencode($output)), ' original:', strlen($output);
```

Which shows the gzipped size and the original size, side by side. I will keep the code as simple as possible, to avoid alienating non-php developers.

---

Here's the results I've gotten from different executions:

- `{"SEARCH":"ui","SORT":"NAME","DISPLAY_FAV":false,"PANEL_POS":0,"MENU_LIST_POS":3,"MAIN_LIST_POS":0,"CHANNEL":""}`
  Result: `gzip:112 original:112` (+0 bytes)
- `{"0":"ui","1":"NAME","3":false,"4":0,"5":3,"6":0}`
  Result: `gzip:65 original:49` (**+16 bytes** over the original)
- `["ui","NAME",false,0,3,0]` (proper JSON output, based on your object)
  Result: `gzip:45 original:25` (**+20 bytes** over the original)

You can try the code on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d8d0799147e3256ede2b730cb1ded7cf66c1eb67

The output was obtained from comments in the question, and not made up by me. Except the last one, which is based on the 2nd output. The 2nd output shows an array being represented as an object (sequencial numeric keys).

---

Okay, I said many words, showed some code and what not. My conclusion?

For your case, either use gzip or use your method. I would stick to plain and simple gzip, and call it a day.

You won't be needlessly increasing your output size.

Even then, if you really want your method, disable gzip and save CPU cicles on your server.